# Annotate Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

i am placing some locations on google map.  i need to set text next to marker on the map. is there a way to do it ?  because i can not see any tools or option provided by google maps to do.

its not an application i am developing or coding. i am just saving locations on google map site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [InfoBox from the utility libraries](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/).  There is [an example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-label.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for reference, i have to do this by using tools when we save address on google maps. not by coding, its not an application i am developing. i am just saving locations on google map.